# Keras to Pytorch model translation and input size

Tags: keras, pytorch

I am following a Keras tutorial and want to shadow it in Pytorch, so am translating. I'm not strongly familiar with either and am coming unstuck on the input size parameter especially, but also the final layer - do I need another Linear layer? Can anyone translate the following to a Pytorch sequential definition?

```python
visible = Input(shape=(64,64,1))
conv1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(pool2)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
```

This is the output of the model:

```python
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
_________________________________________________________________
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 64, 64, 1)         0         
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 61, 61, 32)        544       
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 30, 30, 32)        0         
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 27, 27, 16)        8208      
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 13, 13, 16)        0         
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 13, 13, 10)        170       
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 13, 13, 1)         11        

Total params: 8,933
Trainable params: 8,933
Non-trainable params: 0
```

What I have worked out lacks a specification for the shape of the input, and I am also a bit perplexed at the translation of stride in the specified Keras model as it uses stride 2 in the MaxPooling2D but doesn't specify this elsewhere - it is perhaps a toy example.

```python
model = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 4),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
      nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 4),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
      nn.Linear(10, 1),
      nn.Sigmoid(),
      )
```